# Finding index of newly added element that is numerically ordered

Tags: python

I'm making a program that gets new numerical values to put into a list in numerical order and I need to know what element is before it in the list or the index before it.

How do I find the index of a newly added element in a list that is ordered numerically?

Comment: Is there a question?  I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to ask.  Additionally, why is `list` being used as a variable name?  This is now shadowing the built in; potentially troublesome later.

Comment: Why the index is *1* - should it be *2* instead - to remain all nums. in order afterwards?

Comment: `list.sort` doesn't really do anything - note that `sort` is a function, not a property also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list that is sorted, you can use the `list.index` function to find the index of an element in the list. You then just need to get the element at that index minus one. Assuming the index isn't zero.

```
>>> lst = [0, 2, 5, 9]
>>> x = 3
>>> lst.append(x)
>>> lst.sort()
>>> n = lst.index(x)
>>> (n-1, lst[n-1])
(1, 2)
```